# Can you stop regions from persisting between launches with CLLocationManager?

Tags: ios, core-location, geofencing, clregion, clcircleregion

Is there a way to prevent CLLocationManager from persisting monitored regions between launches? Every time the app is launched I need to add a new set of monitored regions and the old ones are no longer useful. Is there a way to either prevent them from persisting or clear all of the old ones at launch time?

Answer (score 6):

Of course you can clear all the regions currently monitored:

```
+(void)clearRegionWatch
{
    for(CLRegion *region in [[WGLocation shared].locationManager monitoredRegions]){
        [[WGLocation shared].locationManager stopMonitoringForRegion:region];
    }
}
```

If you had a specific identifier that you wanted to remove:

```
+(void)clearRegionWatchForKey:(NSString *)key
{
    for(CLRegion *region in [[WGLocation shared].locationManager monitoredRegions]){
        if([region.identifier isEqualToString:key]){
            [[WGLocation shared].locationManager stopMonitoringForRegion:region];
        }
    }
}
```

You can copy the internals of the function into an appropriate place in your application. I've copied them from my shared manager class.

Comment: I've found this to be unreliable. Sometimes it stops monitoring all of the regions, other times it only stops monitoring some of them.

Comment: Interesting, in that case, have you considered reusing the same identifiers? This will overwrite the regions that "are no longer useful"

Answer (score 2):

In **SWIFT 4**
you can stop all the regions from being monitored like

```
let monitoredRegions = locationManager.monitoredRegions

for region in monitoredRegions{
    locationManager.stopMonitoring(for: region)
}
```